# How to combine taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I use Taxonomy with Contextual Filter, so I can categorize content (nodes), associating taxonomy terms to each content, and filter them in a View.

I can have a node and 2 different vocabularies, lets say **A = {1,2,3}** and **B={a,b,c}**. I can, by default in Drupal usual behaviour, associate a node with multiple values of A and B, lets say that node Nid has associated 1,2 and a,b.

What I need, if it is at all possible, is to have paired associations, i.e., not only 1,2 and a,b separatedly, but in combination. Let's say
`{1,a}` and `{2,b}` and the contextual filter or equivalent, if looking for `{1,a}` will return the node, but if looking for `{1,b}` it will return nothing. Of course, `{1,all}` would have to return the node.

Is there such a module or behaviour in Drupal 7 ?

**Note:** the problem does not lie with the search or filter part. The very basic problem is how to assign a combined value to the node, in the very first place. Later I will face the problem of looking for or filtering for that data. But I don't know how to merge both taxonomy fields into one, so the node is assigned to {1,a} and not to "1" and "a" separatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always need to search on multiple terms at the same time? And how do you want to search, via an exposed filter or with query parameters?

In both cases you need to add references to the vocabularies A and B.

If you want to search through an exposed filter, you can add the term name fields (with relation to the references) to the normal filter and just expose them. I'm not sure, but I think there is a way to combine this with global text search.

If you want to work with query parameters you need contextual filters. Just add a term name for both vocabularies and let them match the value of the query parameters. You can specify what results must be shown if the parameter value is 'all' for example.

I don't think you need the or operator because you mentioned you want to match on both terms at the same time. However, if you want to match on multiple combinations you might want to check this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or). I haven't tested it myself, but it really saves you some time if it works. The or operator is not native in contextual filters.

Good luck! Contextual filters and references can be a real pain in the ...

Comment: I want to look for a query, not exposed filter. As for the problem, the filter or search part is the secondary. I don't know, in first place, how to set up a node with that combination. I have two fields in the node edit screen. One field for one taxonomy term. How do I put a combined term?

Comment: No offence, but was my answer that bad it deserved a down vote? That said, there is a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/combined_termref) for combining multiple vocabularies in a term reference field. However, it is slightly outdated and isn't supported by views (see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2570759)). Maybe it is easier to find a solution using seperate fields as you have now. You might find some more info regarding your problem in this similar [Drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1623054).

Comment: Sorry, I clicked on the down vote by mistake. I am trying to use Entity Reference module instead of Combined termref, mainly because I need Views, but I am not able to make it work. Even thinking of using Fields Collection with the taxonomies. I am completely at lost here in such an apparently easy subject.

Comment: Is there a reason you want a combined field?

Comment: Yes. I need this example to work: Taxonomy Music Genre: Jazz, Rock. Taxonomy Label: Brand1, Brand2. With that, I need a node to be assigned to the combination Jazz-Brand 1 and Rock-Brand 2, so if I look in the Views for the combination Rock-Brand 1 it will not yield any result.

Comment: I have solved by means of extremely simple solution, see attached solution.

Comment: Alright, glad you've found a solution. Simple solutions are the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solutions, which is very simple: Field Collection. I can group the taxonomies and other fields. I have checked with a View with exposed filters and works perfectly.

[image: Field Collections]